# Special cents notation in currency

Tags: formatting, catcodes, detokenize

I made a code that has a special way to write the cents.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@thecomma
\def\normal@comma{,}
{
 \catcode`\,=\active
 \gdef,{
    \if@thecomma
        \expandafter\special@comma
    \else
        \expandafter\normal@comma
    \fi}
}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\,=\active}
\def\special@comma#1#2{
    \ifx#1,
    \else
        \ifmmode
            \hspace{-0.1em}\normal@comma{\raisebox{-0.10em}{\hspace{-0.28em}\scalebox{0.94}{$^{#1#2}$}}}\@thecommafalse
        \else
            ,#1#2
        \fi
    \fi
}
\def\U{\ifmmode\@thecommatrue\scalebox{0.95}{\scalebox{0.98}{U\hspace{0.05em}\scalebox{0.96}{$\$$}}}\hspace{0.2em}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

I spent $\U213,22$ in last month.

\end{document}
```

This code it's working for many purposes, but I'm having a conflict with TikZ node - not so clear why. Any sugestions to get a better code, without that corner cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it's easier to stick with standard LaTeX notation for arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\U}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{%
  \mbox{\normalfont U\$\,\Uinner#1}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Uinner}{mm}{%
  #1,%
  \Uraise{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{00}{#2}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Uraise}{m}{%
  \begingroup\sbox{0}{0}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht0-\height}{\scriptsize#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

I spent \U{213,22} in last month and \U{10} today.

\end{document}
```

[image]